# Redux actions.merge not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I'm trying to populate my react-redux-form with some initial values based on an object retrieved by API call.

What i do -> Component mounts -> ajax call fires (creates object)-> returns promise -> try to set initial form values.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    retrieveIrfItems(this.props.selected.Id).then((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        this.props.setDefaultFields(item[0]);
    });
}
```

I checked pretty much every tutorial out there and this is what i tried ->

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    checkToken: token => dispatch(checkToken(token)),
    changeField: (model, e) => dispatch(actions.change(model, e)),
    setDefaultFields: (values) => actions.merge('editItem', values)
});
```

`setDefaultFields` never fires. No errors, no change. Any tips?

Comment: why did you ignore dispatch function here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to dispatch

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    checkToken: token => dispatch(checkToken(token)),
    changeField: (model, e) => dispatch(actions.change(model, e)),
    // NB next line
    setDefaultFields: (values) => dispatch(actions.merge('editItem', values))
});
```

BTW you could provide an object as `mapDispatchToProps`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  checkToken,
  changeField: actions.change,
  setDefaultFiels: values => actions.merge('editItem', values)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its not really "forgot" as in i didnt know i need to dispatch for every action in redux-form as well. Still learning about redux and i (literally) followed a short tutorial regarding this. Seems like that tutorial is broken.

Comment: @DanteR. You may also provide an object as `mapDispatchToProps`. `connect` will bind action creators to dispatch automagically.

Comment: Just saw your edit, it means the tutorial wasnt broken, only my knowledge. May i ask whats the point of having `dispatch` if it works with an object? For unconnected components or something else? Thanks.

Comment: `dispatch` is absolutely essential to whole redux architecture. It is the only way to actually notify store about action. But the way you access the `store.dispatch` may vary. If you need full control over how you would dispatch action - you provide a function that implements whatever logic you need. If  you have a bunch of action creators you could simply pass an object so  connect would wrap each action creator w/ dispatch for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a map `setDefaultFields: (values) => actions.merge('editItem', values)` but you haven't dispatched it, your action reaches the Reducer only when you **dispatch** it.

[image]

make this change to dispatch it

```
setDefaultFields: (values) => dispatch(actions.merge('editItem', values))
```

also, don't forget to use **mapDispatchToProps** in connect

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(yourcomponent);
```